# SQL table column forming from another columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a create table query, where I'm creating a table from another table's data. But I'm supposed to create new column from the same row's data.

In example below, I need to get the first letter from ID from each row.

For example what I have tried:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ID
                          FROM tableWhereDataComes), 1, 1)) AS PERSONTYPE,
       ID , --This is a string like M101 or F101 etc.
       FIRSTNAME,
       LASTNAME
FROM tableWhereDataComes
```

How do I get the required M or F to the first column PERSONTYPE?

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: FYI, Functions don't need to be preceeded with a `SELECT` nor do that need to be wrapped in parenthesis.

Comment: Why do you need to intentionally duplicate data? This could all be done in a view,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for `LEFT()`?

```
SELECT LEFT(ID, 1) AS PERSONTYPE, ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM tableWhereDataComes;
```

I would note that this is probably not necessary.  You can add a computed column to the table:

```
alter table tableWhereDataComes add persontype as (left(id, 1));
```

This is then calculated when the table is queried (or if persisted whenever the data changes), so it is always up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. LEFT() is new to me, so it's great to learn something new.